# Why is this implementation for checking balanced binary tree wrong

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

```
public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return true;
        int rightCount = maxDepth(root.right);
        int leftCount = maxDepth(root.left);
        if(Math.abs(rightCount-leftCount)<=1) return true;
        return false;
    }
    public int maxDepth(TreeNode root){
       if(root == null) return 0;
        return Math.max(maxDepth(root.left),maxDepth(root.right))+1;
    }
```

Checking the max depth for both branches and determining if the absolute value is <=1

Comment: Depends. Do you consider a tree with two long, linear left and right arms to be balanced? They would have the same depth, but the tree wouldn't be very full, so operations on this tree would tend to be linear instead of logarithmic. Essentially a tree like `1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 5 (root) -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9`. Both the left and right branches of the root have the same depth (4), but is this tree balanced?

Answer (score 0):

At first:

If you have invalid root arg `isBalanced` returns `true`, so that is bad implementation, despite the fact that code *could* have no errors.

In my opinion, function should work with valid arguments, otherwise throw exception (error?).

Also check this solution, read code and try to do something like this:

```c
/* C program to check if a tree is height-balanced or not */
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define bool int 
  
/* A binary tree node has data, pointer to left child 
   and a pointer to right child */
struct node { 
    int data; 
    struct node* left; 
    struct node* right; 
}; 
  
/* Returns the height of a binary tree */
int height(struct node* node); 
  
/* Returns true if binary tree with root as root is height-balanced */
bool isBalanced(struct node* root) 
{ 
    int lh; /* for height of left subtree */
    int rh; /* for height of right subtree */
  
    /* If tree is empty then return true */
    if (root == NULL) 
        return 1; 
  
    /* Get the height of left and right sub trees */
    lh = height(root->left); 
    rh = height(root->right); 
  
    if (abs(lh - rh) <= 1 && isBalanced(root->left) && isBalanced(root->right)) 
        return 1; 
  
    /* If we reach here then tree is not height-balanced */
    return 0; 
} 
  
/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS TO TEST isBalanced() FUNCTION */
  
/* returns maximum of two integers */
int max(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return (a >= b) ? a : b; 
} 
  
/*  The function Compute the "height" of a tree. Height is the 
    number of nodes along the longest path from the root node 
    down to the farthest leaf node.*/
int height(struct node* node) 
{ 
    /* base case tree is empty */
    if (node == NULL) 
        return 0; 
  
    /* If tree is not empty then height = 1 + max of left 
      height and right heights */
    return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right)); 
} 
  
/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the 
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int data) 
{ 
    struct node* node = (struct node*) 
        malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    node->data = data; 
    node->left = NULL; 
    node->right = NULL; 
  
    return (node); 
} 
  
int main() 
{ 
    struct node* root = newNode(1); 
    root->left = newNode(2); 
    root->right = newNode(3); 
    root->left->left = newNode(4); 
    root->left->right = newNode(5); 
    root->left->left->left = newNode(8); 
  
    if (isBalanced(root)) 
        printf("Tree is balanced"); 
    else
        printf("Tree is not balanced"); 
  
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

([copy & pasted from here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/))